# how to hold a session with passport?

Tags: node.js, redux, passport.js, passport-local

So, i'd like my user session to persist upon login/signup, which it does not.

The official documentation says to add this to start with :

```
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

which I did. Then it goes on to specify :

*In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a user will only be transmitted during the login request. If authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser.
Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session. In order to support login sessions, Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to and from the session.*

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serialize user: ", user);
  done(null, user[0]._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

If I understand correctly, upon login, the user should see a new cookie being set. 
My serialize and deserialize functions seem to work. The console will log the user details after I login a user. No error message in the console.
However, I don't see any cookie when I login a user.

Am I supposed to add an additional command manually ? something like this :

```
res.cookie('userid', user.id, { maxAge: 2592000000 });
```

I am using Redux, so am I supposed to deal with the persistent session via the reducer instead, with my authenticated (true or false) variable ?

I think I am a bit confused right now between what is supposed to be done on the server side and what is supposed to be done on the client side.

Answer (score 4):

```
//npm modules
const express = require('express');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4')
const session = require('express-session')
const FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const users = [
  {id: '2f24vvg', email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password'}
]

// configure passport.js to use the local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  { usernameField: 'email' },
  (email, password, done) => {
    console.log('Inside local strategy callback')
    // here is where you make a call to the database
    // to find the user based on their username or email address
    // for now, we'll just pretend we found that it was users[0]
    const user = users[0] 
    if(email === user.email && password === user.password) {
      console.log('Local strategy returned true')
      return done(null, user)
    }
  }
));

// tell passport how to serialize the user
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('Inside serializeUser callback. User id is save to the session file store here')
  done(null, user.id);
});

// create the server
const app = express();

// add & configure middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    console.log('Inside session middleware genid function')
    console.log(`Request object sessionID from client: ${req.sessionID}`)
    return uuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  store: new FileStore(),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// create the homepage route at '/'
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Inside the homepage callback')
  console.log(req.sessionID)
  res.send(`You got home page!\n`)
})

// create the login get and post routes
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Inside GET /login callback')
  console.log(req.sessionID)
  res.send(`You got the login page!\n`)
})

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Inside POST /login callback')
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    console.log('Inside passport.authenticate() callback');
    console.log(`req.session.passport: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`)
    console.log(`req.user: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`)
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      console.log('Inside req.login() callback')
      console.log(`req.session.passport: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`)
      console.log(`req.user: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}`)
      return res.send('You were authenticated & logged in!\n');
    })
  })(req, res, next);
})

// tell the server what port to listen on
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on localhost:3000')
})
```

try going through the link
https://medium.com/@evangow/server-authentication-basics-express-sessions-passport-and-curl-359b7456003d

Answer (score 1):

1
Check hostname.
In my case, cookie was set on `127.0.0.1`, not `localhost`.

2
Make sure `express session` is called before `passport session`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using **mongoose** with **expressjs** and **passportjs**, You can try this method below. This also keeps the cookie saved after the server restart. For other databases you can check the [Expressjs Compatible Session Stores List](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/README.md#compatible-session-stores)

```js
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

// before this setup mongoose connection then add this code.
app.use(
  session({
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      ttl: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, // = 365 days.
    }),
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: app.get("env") === "production",
    },
  })
);
```